# Sql query interrupted by server for a table with over 1m records?

Tags: php, sql, magento, phpmyadmin, report

I have a website created in Magento with approx 1120 products in there.

When I select the bulit-in Magento menu option: Reports -> Products -> Most Viewed, then enter in a date range and select "Show By" = [Day], I get a timeout error. But the SAME report but where "Show By" = [Month] and "Show By" = [Year], runs to completion and the report is generated.

Upon investigation, I found table [Report_Event] has in excess of 1 million records. When I tried to run the SAME query in PHPMyAdmin, I get message: "SQL query was interrupted by server".

Has anybody come across this error? Is there a workaround or a setting that needs to be applied?

Answer (score 2):

Try to increase `max_execution_time` of your server or script. To do this for server - change corresponding parameter in `php.ini`. To do this in your script use `ini_set(max_execution_time,$amount)` where `$amount` is allowed time for script to be executed in seconds. If you want to test how long it takes use `ini_set(max_execution_time,0)`. There is a couple of good answers here - [On using ini_set('max_execution_time', 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523164/on-using-ini-setmax-execution-time-0)

As for Magento try to place `ini_set(max_execution_time,$amount)` at the beginning of index.php.