# Place max_execution_time in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a client who has a php script execution timeout problem on a locally installed wordpress. I dont have an access to machine to do the test, so here is my question.

There is a custom plugin on that site that has all the php custom code in it. Can I just place:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

on top of plugin file and be sure it will work for entire front and back end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting sets the execution time for the entire execution of your script. You don't necessarily have to place it on the top of the plugin file, you can set it in a method or function that takes longer to run. Either way, it should be fine.

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523164/on-using-ini-setmax-execution-time-0) question.