# Increase page execution time in php

Tags: php

I am designing an web app which should generate more than 10000 entries at a time. All code works fine but I got an error as server timed out after 2-3 minutes of execution. At the top of the page I mentioned

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

as set to 0 = infinity but still page execution stops after 2-3 minutes. Is there any solution for this? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you had restart your server after this ?

Comment: @DeepKakkar - He is mentioning it in php file which does not requires server restart.

Comment: ok thanks. I got knowledge

Comment: PHP usually times out after 30 seconds if nothing else is specified. So this seems to be a problem with your webserver, not with PHP, since the script runs longer.

Comment: What you got after execution?

Answer (score 0):

There are many places to timeout:

- PHP scripts via :
- [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) ini setting, already covered
- [set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit) which is basically the same as above
- [max_input_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) which defaults to infinity so this likely isn't the issue
- Client timeouts, which may be different depending on the browser (often default to somewhere between 2 and 5 minutes), or may be modified in JavaScript, on the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout) object for example.
- Some sort of middleware specific to your configuration, perhaps a configuration parameter in a reverse proxy like nginx or apache, or some sort of FastCGI setting.

Good luck finding it.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to check that Is your server run your site in safe mode or not because You can not change this setting with `ini_set()` when running in safe mode. Many hosts run in safe mode so better to check first.

`max_execution_time` only limits the script execution time of itself i.e. `CPU` time of your script.

In case if you do with `set_time_limit()` then the same restriction is in place on `set_time_limit()`.

`set_time_limit()` is indeed just a convenience wrapper around the according `ini_set()` call.
You can check difference between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914257/difference-between-set-time-limit-and-ini-setmax-execution-time).

Second, after set time limit then you should also set the memory limit with `ini_set('memory_limit','32M');` . memory unit depends upon your requirement.

Using this condition you can check that Is your limit function effects value or not

```
echo 'Time Limit = ' . ini_get('max_execution_time') .
```

So better to check result with changes. This way you can check, Is your changes working or not, if not then you need to consult with support